# Subconscious vs subconsciousness

Tags: grammar

Which one of the following sentences is correct ?

- That comes from my subconsciousness.
- That comes from my subconscious.

Comment: What is the difference between these words?

Comment: Both may be used, but the variant using 'subconscious' as the noun is far more common.

Comment: @LittleEva: one is a noun; the other is not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: the second sentence is more informal.  More than most languages, English allows for implicit subjects, particularly in informal use, eg. "Grand and State is next" for "[The station at] Grand and State is next."  The second sentence also has an implied subject: "That comes from my subconscious [mind]."

Comment: @scottb - my comment was directed at the OP and intended to elicit some further information concerning their research and thoughts on the subject.

Comment: @scottb The first substantive usage of subconscious 'is attested from 1886' (Etymon). It has had time to undergo zero conversion to the noun since then. In 5 online dictionaries I've checked, it's given as a noun, unflagged for 'informal' etc register. The Wikipedia article swaps between n and adj usage. Scientific American has:
11 May 2015 - A third tool researchers can use to probe the subconscious is the IAT...  You're getting close to the etymological fallacy here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: no argument, however English is always this way.  English has no standards body, and so words evolve by precedent.  The people at Merriam-Webster have famously described themselves as "overly permissive descriptivists."  In the sentence above, because the use of subconscious does not refer to an abstract concept, I favor that it is an adjective with an implicit subject but there's no rule that proves that it isn't a noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you would learn a lot more from looking at the OED. They have adjectival examples from 1834.

Comment: @scottb: argument. I don't accept that 'the second sentence is more informal'. And I'll go with AHDEL, Collins, M-W, RHK Webster's ... (and also OED, as WS2 concedes) ... and quite a few scientific articles of obviously formal register on the internet ... in rapidly concluding that 'one is a noun; the other is not' is obviously an arrogation.

Comment: @WS2 And that proves? ODO / AHDEL / CDO / M-W / Collins (and, I'll wager, OED) already list the relevant sense of 'mobile' (obviously a deleted form of 'mobile phone') as a true noun (which makes sense, as it inflects for number). Are we back to the etymological fallacy (that's what it used to mean / how it used to be used, so novel usages shouldn't be considered correct)? Zero conversion.

Answer (score 4):

**Subconscious**
The OED has two adjectival senses and a noun sense. Examples of the noun date from 1877 (adjectival goes back a little earlier - early 19th C), and I suspect closely correlates with the emergence of psychology as a modern discipline. The adjectival examples have some religious connotations among them.

**Subconsciousness** has only noun senses.

What does seem to me to emerge from looking at this is that the noun *subconscious* tends to be used either with the definite article, or in describing that of a specific person e.g. *his subconscious, Fred's subconscious etc*, to refer to an aspect of the mind of an individual. *Subsonsciousness* seems to have a more amorphous use, an abstract noun which refers to the condition in general.

**I do believe there to be a difference in the way the two words are used**. Were I trying to psychoanalyse you (I do not have that ability, you will be relieved to know) I might refer to your *subconscious*. Were I talking about psychology in general I might say something like *The current generation of cognitive psychologists place less emphasis on 'subconsciousness' as a route to understanding human behaviour*.

Comment: I agree that "the subsconcious" is best used as an abstraction.  When referring to a particular person's mind or behavior, subconscious is best used as an adjective.

Comment: @scottb But no reason why I couldn't talk about my own *subconscious*, as part of a general conversation on *subconsciousness*.

Comment: Correct.  What you're really saying is "my own subconscious [mind | motives]" (unless the rest of the sentence evokes a generalization or abstraction).  With the adoption of the adjective as a noun, the English word subconscious has lost precision ... but this has been the fate of many words in English.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. There seems to be some difference of opinion within the comments above. As far as I know, both *subconscious* and *subconsciousness* are nouns. *Subconscious* is also an adjective:

> **subconscious**
>   noun [S] uk   /ˌsʌbˈkɒn.ʃəs/  us   /-ˈkɑːn-/
>   › the part of your mind that notices and remembers information when you are not actively trying to do so, and influences your behaviour even though you do not realize it: The memory was buried deep within my subconscious.
>
> **subconscious**
>   adjective [before noun] uk   /ˌsʌbˈkɒn.ʃəs/  us   /-ˈkɑːn-/
>   › relating to this part of your mind: subconscious thoughts/fears Such memories exist only on/at the subconscious level. Our subconscious mind registers things which our conscious mind is not aware of.
>   *[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/subconscious)*

But [*Merriam Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subconscious) seems to give *subconscious* only as an adjective:

> **subconscious** adjective sub·con·scious \ˌsəb-ˈkän(t)-shəs, ˈsəb-\
>
> : existing in the part of the mind that a person is not aware of :
>   existing in the mind but not consciously known or felt

and reserves **subconsciousness** as the noun.

Here's an account of Freud's uses of his original German version:

> As for the term “subconscious,” Freud used it interchangeably with
>   “unconscious” at the outset. The words are similarly close but not
>   identical in German (subconscious is das Unterbewusste; unconscious is
>   das Unbewusste). - [*Harvard Health*](http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/unconscious-or-subconscious-20100801255)

You can see that, in this quote, **subconscious** is used as a noun, translating the two German nouns.

So, going on the limited sample of MW and Cambridge (note the [uk] in the latter), is the use of the word as a noun limited to the UK? (But Harvard is on the other side of the great divide).

My feeling is that *the subconscious* is a Freudian reference, and therefore more closely related to psychoanalysis, whereas *subconsciousness* is a more general, lay use of the idea. Although the Harvard article implies we'd be better of with *unconscious*?

Comment: Oh, there have been some more comments and another answer with similar ideas posted at the same time as this.

Comment: That happened to me, too. When I tried to error-read my post, two other post showed up after clicking the button. :-)

Comment: Freud was born in 1856. He didn't begin this part of his work until 1890 and his first book *On Aphasia* was not published until 1891. OED adjectival references to *subconscious* begin as early as 1834, and the noun references start in 1877. The notion of the *subconscious* is clearly not entirely due to Freud (any more than communism started with Marx). But it was part of the *zeitgeist* of the late nineteenth century, when science and society began looking for more profound and more obscure explanations for things than they had been provided by the 17th century Enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct.

> 1. That comes from my subconsciousness.
> 2. That comes from my subconscious.

Clearly *subconsciousness* is only a noun. *Subconscious* is a noun and an adjective, too. ***

I (non-native-speaker) never knew before thinking about and "googling" in regard of your question, that the latter can be both, so I would have understood *subconscious*, as **scottb** ** told in his comment or to be a mistake of the writer. If someone implies a additional word it might not be the one you had in mind, e.g.

> That comes from my subconscious desires.

gives an additional meaning, when the intended word would have been *mind*.

So you might prefer *subconsciousness* to *subconscious* when you use it as a noun, as it is not to misunderstand and therefore gives less room for interpretation.

---

** @EdwinAshworth: the second sentence is more informal. More than most languages, English allows for implicit subjects, particularly in informal use, eg. "Grand and State is next" for "[The station at] Grand and State is next." The second sentence also has an implied subject: "That comes from my subconscious [mind]." - scottb

---

*** First hit on google for "subconscious":

> ### sub·con·scious
>
> səbˈkänSHəs
>
> #### adjective
>
> 1.
>   of or concerning the part of the mind of which one is not fully aware but which influences one's actions and feelings.
>   "my subconscious fear"
>   synonyms:   unconscious, latent, suppressed, repressed, subliminal, dormant, underlying, innermost; informalbottled up
>   "subconscious desires"
>
> #### noun
>
> 1.
>   the subconscious part of the mind (not in technical use in psychoanalysis, where unconscious is preferred).
>   synonyms:   (unconscious) mind, imagination, inner(most) self, psyche
>   "the creative powers of the subconscious"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The placement of adverbs in English seems to be my crux. Thank you for editing.