# Why is "subconscious" used as a noun, while "conscious" is not?

Tags: parts-of-speech, irregular

`subconscious` and `subconsciousness`
`conscious` and `consciousness`.

While each one has a noun counterpart that is explicitly a noun, why is it that only `subconscious` is also used as a noun while `conscious` is not?

Some background info on `subconscious` and `subconsciousness`:

[Subconscious vs subconsciousness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253124/subconscious-vs-subconsciousness)

TLDR: `subconscious` and `subconsciousness` have slightly different meanings, even both as nouns. But that still begs the question, "Why not the symmetrical counterpart to `conscious` and `consciousness`

I'm going to give the benefit of the doubt and ask the question openly and give it all objective reasoning, but my most probable hypothesis is that English & people are quite asystematic, and this is just an ad hoc clusterfrack phenomenon of language evolving without thought... or subconsciously, if you'll permit my bastardization of that term.

Comment: thx for the typo catch. typos are usually lowest on my priority list when editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Conscious* is used as a noun:

> In psychoanalysis, the component of waking awareness perceptible by a person at any given instant; consciousness.

([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=conscious))

As an example, from [*Contemporary Theories and Systems in Psychology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2KigBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA302&dq=%22conscious%20in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpisH8lJHRAhXD4yYKHUZkBUgQ6AEITTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22conscious%20in%22&f=false) by B B Wolman:

> The **conscious** in Jung's theory plays a secondary role as compared to the unconscious.

Comment: While it’s true that *conscious* can be used as a noun. I think  the word you need in your sentence above is *conscience*.

Comment: @Jim At the risk of ruining a joke, it's a pun. Clare is playing on the word *conscience* while saying that her mind is clear on the issue because she has evidence for her first statement.

Comment: @deadrat-  I love puns. My wife punches me in the arm everytime I make one.  she does the same when my daughter makes one because it’s clearly my fault. But I didn’t see this as one. I get it, but I wish I didn’t.

Comment: so if we put `the` in front of `conscious` / `subconscious` we're talking about the abstraction? Or is it synonymous with `consciousness` / `subconsciousness`? I don't fully get accepted answer of the link in my OP